# To check whether a number is multiple of second number

Tags: python, numbers

I want to check whether a number is multiple of second. What's wrong with the following code?

```
def is_multiple(x,y):
    if x!=0 & (y%x)==0 :
       print("true")
    else:
       print("false")
    end
print("A program in python")
x=input("enter a number :")
y=input("enter its multiple :")
is_multiple(x,y)
```

error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: you need to convert x to int or `int(input(...`

Comment: Be careful regarding which version of python you use (mainly if you are using a python version different from the one used in the tutorial you are reading), because `input` is different in python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the *binary AND operator* `&`; you want the *boolean AND operator* here, `and`:

```
x and (y % x) == 0
```

Next, you want to get your inputs converted to integers:

```
x = int(input("enter a number :"))
y = int(input("enter its multiple :"))
```

You'll get a `NameError` for that `end` expression on a line, drop that altogether, Python doesn't need those.

You can test for *just* `x`; in a boolean context such as an `if` statement, a number is considered to be false if 0:

```
if x and y % x == 0:
```

Your function `is_multiple()` should probably just return a boolean; leave printing to the part of the program doing all the other input/output:

```
def is_multiple(x, y):
    return x and (y % x) == 0

print("A program in python")
x = int(input("enter a number :"))
y = int(input("enter its multiple :"))
if is_multiple(x, y):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

That last part could simplified if using a conditional expression:

```
print("A program in python")
x = int(input("enter a number :"))
y = int(input("enter its multiple :"))
print("true" if is_multiple(x, y) else "false")
```

Comment: "you want to get your inputs converted to integers" - Why? The question is "check whether a **number** is multiple of second number", not "check whether an integer ...". For example, imho 4.4 is a multiple of 1.1. Only the factor itself, here 4, must be an integer (else the whole concept doesn't make sense).

Comment: @ChrisK.: because floating point and clean division do not usually mix, making `int()` *far more likely*.  While `4.4 % 1.1` is exactly `0.0`, that's far from typical. Try with `3.3` instead of `4.4`, for example.

Comment: @ChrisK.: Note that I answered here with *people new to programming* in mind, because that's clearly the case here. Teachers that ask students to write functions like these (and this is *definitely* something written for a homework, course or book exercise or assignment) definitely have integers in mind *because* having this is a much more complex issue when floating point values are involved.

Answer (score 4):

Some things to mention:

1. Conditions with `and`, not `&` (binary operator)
2. Convert input to numbers (for example using `int()`) - you might also want to catch if something other than a number is entered

This should work:

```
def is_multiple(x,y):
    if x != 0 and y%x == 0:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

print("A program in python")
x = int(input("enter a number :"))
y = int(input("enter its multiple :"))
is_multiple(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` operator instead of bitwise `&` operator.

You need to conver values to integers using `int()`

```
def is_multiple(x,y):
    if x!=0 and (y%x)==0 :
       print("true")
    else:
       print("false")

print("A program in python")
x = int(input("enter a number :"))
y = int(input("enter its multiple :"))
is_multiple(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked also for when x and/or y are equal to 0. Idk if there's a shorter way of writing it.

Tested with (4,12), (12, 4), (2,0), (0,2), (0, 0)
(result should be : False True False True True).

```
def exo1(x,y):
    #x = int(input("input number x: "))
    #y = int(input("input number y: "))
    if x==0 and y==0:
        return True 
    if x>0 and y==0:
        return False 
    if y>0 and x==0:
        return True 
    if x!=0 and y!=0 and (x%y)==0: 
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(exo1())
print(exo1(4,12))
print(exo1(12,4))
print(exo1(2,0))
print(exo1(0,2))
print(exo1(0,0))
```